# What should I add to the URL parameters tool to solve "Indexed although blocked by robots.txt"

Tags: google-search-console, url-parameters

I have an online shop. Google search console is warning that a URL is "Indexed although blocked by robots.txt".  When I use Google's robots.txt tool, I see that the page is blocked by this rule.

[image]

I am building my website with [OXID](https://www.oxid-esales.com/en/) and when I [asked in their forums](https://forum.oxid-esales.com/t/warnung-von-search-google-com-wegen-robots-txt/97954) (in German), say that all URLs with `*?cur=x`  will be excluded to avoid duplicate content.  To solve this problem, I should add a few parameters to Google Search Console URL-Parameter tool rather than changing robots.txt.

[image]

Which URL parameter should be added here?